# error org.springframework.core.ErrorCoded when i update version of spring-core

Tags: java, spring, maven

Good morning
I want your help
I have a batch with spring batch which contains the CVE-2022-22965 vulnerability and to fix this vulnerability I have to upgrade spring-core to version 5.2.20.RELEASE and when I upgrade the spring-core version the batch does not run I get the error

```
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.createBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:200) ~[spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:126) ~[spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452) ~[spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139) ~[spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83) ~[spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:284) [spring-batch-core-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:577) [spring-batch-core-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.ErrorCoded`

this maven tree

```
enter code here [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:provided
```

[INFO] |  |  |  |  - org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:provided

[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.4.3.RELEASE:compile

[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:provided

[INFO] |  |  |  |  - org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:provided

[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:provided

[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:provided

[INFO] |  - org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.6.3.RELEASE:compile

[INFO] |     - org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:provided

[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.20.RELEASE:provided

[INFO] |  - org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.20.RELEASE:provided

Thank you

Comment: You need to be consistent with your dependencies, if you are to upgrade something in spring do it completely or don't do it at all.